# Set default baseURLString using manager session configuration

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm developing an IOS app using swift with Alamofire library. Two files of my network model are described below, the first one is the ApiClient Class with the Alamofire manager session configuration and 2 instances of the services,in my question I'm only describing one, the Service1 struct, in this struct I'm using the Alamofire Router to request to the REST API, and I would like to know, How can I set a default baseURLString ("https://api.com/v1") using manager session configuration? instead of declare it inside each struct Service.

ApiClient.swift

```js
class ApiClient {

    var OAuthToken = "ZMpMDJhB0egjFIzFhapuWNFSBhX2conQ1e+3vlv0XrJQVcw7fRg=="

    var service1: Service1
    var service2: Service2


    init() {

        let manager = Manager.sharedInstance

        manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "Bearer \(OAuthToken)"
        ]

        service1 = Service1()
        service2 = Service2()
    }


}
```

Service1.swift

```js
struct Service1 {

    enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {

        static let baseURLString = "https://api.com/v1"

        case GetList([String: AnyObject])
        case GetById(String)
        case Add([String: AnyObject])
        case Update(String, [String: AnyObject])
        case Delete(String)
        case GetListFromPoint([String: AnyObject])

        var method: Alamofire.Method {
            switch self {
            case .GetList:
                return .GET
            case .GetById:
                return .GET
            case .Add:
                return .POST
            case .Update:
                return .PUT
            case .Delete:
                return .DELETE
            case .GetListFromPoint:
                return .GET
            }
        }

        var path: String {
            switch self {
            case .GetList:
                return "/endPoint"
            case .GetById(let id):
                return "/endPoint/\(id)"
            case .Add:
                return "/endPoint"
            case .Update(let id, _):
                return "/endPoint/\(id)"
            case .Delete(let id):
                return "/endPoint/\(id)"
            case .GetListFromPoint:
                return "/near/endPoint"
            }
        }

        var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {
            let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)!
            let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
            mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue

            switch self {
            case .GetList(let parameters):
                return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
            case .Add(let parameters):
                return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
            case .Update(_, let parameters):
                return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
            case .GetListFromPoint(let parameters):
                return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
            default:
                return mutableURLRequest
            }
        }
    }


    func getList(completionHandler: ([Object1]?, NSError?) -> ()) {

        Alamofire.request(Router.GetList(["skip": 0, "limit": 100])).responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
             //Converting json to object

    }

    func getById(completionHandler: ([Object1]?, NSError?) -> ()) {

        Alamofire.request(Router.GetById(id)).responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
           //Converting json to object

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there are MANY ways you could do this. Here are a few ideas...

1. Store the `baseURLString` in the `APIClient` and pass the value into each of the `Service` initializers
2. Create a `BaseService` class where you store all common types of information between the services such as `baseURLString`, additional headers, etc.
3. Expose the `baseURLString` in the `APIClient` and pass a weak reference of the `APIClient` into each service.
4. Create a separate object such as an `AppEnvironment` that stores properties such as OAuth info, `baseURLString`, etc. that can be accessed through either a global singleton or class properties.

And there are many more ways. Hopefully one of those ideas triggers your imagination.

Comment: thanks for these ideas cnoon, but my goal is the services mustn't know anything about APIClient and if I pass the URL by reference, singleton... I have to instantiate it inside each service --> ApiClient.Url. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well the answer to your original question that you asked is No, you cannot set the `baseURLString` using the session manager configuration. It doesn't support the idea of a base URL. Therefore, you need to use inheritance, a global value, dependency injection, etc. to make sure your `Service` objects have access to the base URL. The easiest solution would be to use inheritance by creating a `BaseService` that sets the `baseURL` and all other `Service` subclasses will inherit it automatically.